# Design superimposed but responsive floating divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

What I'm trying to do is to have superimposed divs just like in the image for a medium screen, but i want them stacked one below the other on small screens:

(I'm using bootstrap :D)

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxxXp.png)

**CSS**

```
#div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#div-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 100px;
}

#div-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="div-1" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-info" style="height: 250px">

    </div>
    <div id="div-2" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-secondary" style="height: 250px">

    </div>
    <div id="div-3" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-dark" style="height: 250px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use media queries in the style of your divs. Take reference from the snippet below. This will stack the divs one over another for width less than 786px or in other words it will follow Bootstrap Style rules when the width is less than 786px.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 786px){
#div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#div-2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 100px;
}

#div-3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  left: 200px;
}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="div-1" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-info" style="height: 250px">

    </div>
    <div id="div-2" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-secondary" style="height: 250px">

    </div>
    <div id="div-3" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 bg-dark" style="height: 250px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help.